# Wrap website with cordova phonegap. What happens with audio files?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a learn new language site, that i want to wrap in cordova phonegap.
The app needs to work offline. I also want to make it available on the app store.

The project budget is very low. I need to find a quick way to create this app within the budget and time frame.

My question.
Is it possible to just wrap the whole site? And save it all offline.
What happens to the database? Do i need to recreate the database for the app, use sqlite ect.

Some pages will have audio files, where user can listen to the word pronunciations. What happens to the audio files. Do i need to rebuild this? Or is there a quicker way.

Can all of this be achieved by using cache?

If there is a better way of doing this please let me know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/) provides a web browser view that displays when calling cordova.InAppBrowser.open().

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

> The cordova.InAppBrowser.open() function is defined to be a drop-in
>   replacement for the window.open() function. Existing window.open()
>   calls can use the InAppBrowser window, by replacing window.open:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs. For this reason, the InAppBrowser is recommended if you need to load third-party (untrusted) content, instead of loading that into the main Cordova webview. The InAppBrowser is not subject to the whitelist, nor is opening links in the system browser.